# JPanel and JMenuBar to the same frame

Tags: java

I can't seem to add both a JMenuBar and a JPanel to my frame?

How come?

Code:

```
package proj;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Proj extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Proj() {
setSize(400,300);
setResizable(false);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setVisible(true);

JMenuBar rodMenu = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Vis");
JMenuItem men_item1 = new JMenuItem("Statestik");

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 240));
wrapper.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

setJMenuBar(rodMenu);
rodMenu.add(menu);
menu.add(men_item1);

add(wrapper);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Proj();
}

}
```

With this code, the panel isn't added, only the menu... If I remove the menu, then the panel appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean panel not appearing? I could see both menu and panel with this code!

[image]

If the problem still persist try moving the setSize(), setResizable() etc block down like

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Proj extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Proj() {
        JMenuBar rodMenu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Vis");
        JMenuItem men_item1 = new JMenuItem("Statestik");

        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 240));
        wrapper.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        setJMenuBar(rodMenu);
        rodMenu.add(menu);
        menu.add(men_item1);

        JButton b = new JButton("Test");
        wrapper.add(b);

        add(wrapper);

        setSize(400, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Proj();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: YES! That's exactly what I want it to look like! Does not look that way when I run?!?!??

Comment: Ok, now I've found that if I run like 20 times in a row, ONE of them will run my code properly!
I hate when code doesn't do the same thing every time I run... Could this be NetBeans?

Comment: Ok, it worked when I moved the "setSize" etc down as you said... I don't quit understand why, but it works, thanks :D

Comment: That is strange. That might be due to some class loading issue? It might might not be taking your changes. However I have seen issues when we try to use setSize(), setVisible(true) etc. first and then try to add components it may not be visible. That is why I asked you to try to move down.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding with

```
this.getContentPane.add(wrapper)
```

instead of

```
add(wrapper)
```